# Error injecting a plain object into an angular 6 service

Tags: angular

I have a service, and I want to inject an object into it when instantiating it

```
import myObj from './myObj'
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' })
export class myService {
  constructor(private myObject: myObj) {}
}
```

The above code doesn't work, how do I make this work?

I've tried to use 
`@Inject(myObj)` in the constructor but that hasn't had any success either..

I get this build error whether I use `@Inject` or not:

```
Error: Internal error: unknown identifier []
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20493:23)
    at /Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9540:33
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at InjectableCompiler.depsArray (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9506:21)
    at InjectableCompiler.factoryFor (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9570:32)
    at InjectableCompiler.injectableDef (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9589:38)
    at InjectableCompiler.compile (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9599:102)
    at /Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20338:86
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._emitPartialModule2 (/Users/oviir/workspace/plugins/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20338:21)
```

Comment: You can only inject services. Not arbitrary objects.

Comment: You can create a new instance of `myObj` if using a service, since likely the service is a singleton. If you want to inject it instead (e.g for mocking in tests), use a [Dependency injection token](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens) to represent `myObj` to the injector.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?  If you just want an instance of that object, do:

```
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' })
export class myService {
  private obj: myObj;
  constructor() {
    this.obj = new myObj();
  }
}
```

Injections are for getting the singleton instance of a shared service in your application, not for getting access to *all* objects in your application.